# Wordpress - No access to dashboard and website

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, hyperlink, permalinks

I have a subdirectory wwith wordpress and I tried to move it to the root directory but everything crashed.

**This is what I did:**
First I changed the Permalinks like this:
- Wordpress URL: http://szumun.com/wordp
- Site URL: http://szumun.com

Then I moved index.php from the subdirectory /wordp into the root directory.

Then I changed the last row of index.php into following:
- require ('./wordp/wp-blog-header.php)

But now I changed the last row into:
- require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' )

### => Now the site loads but without the style/template

I have no access to the dashboard anymore.
The website returns this error: ***"Warning: require(/home/.sites/825/site3695042/web/wordpwp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.sites/825/site3695042/web/wordp/index.php on line 17 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/.sites/825/site3695042/web/wordpwp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /home/.sites/825/site3695042/web/wordp/index.php on line 17"***

Can someone please help me? I would highly appreciate it.

The website is: www.szumun.com/wordp |
Subdirectory: /wordp |
Homepage: www.szumun.com

I tried to modify the files but it didn't work.

Comment: How did you move? Did you moved all the files and changed the db wp_options table?

Comment: First I changed the Permalinks like this:
- Wordpress URL: http://szumun.com/wordp
- Site URL: http://szumun.com

Then I moved index.php from the subdirectory /wordp into the root directory.

Then I changed the last row of index.php into following:
- require ('./wordp/wp-blog-header.php)

But now I changed the last row into:
- require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' )
=> Now the site loads but without the style/template

Answer (score 0):

On line 17 of `wordp/index.php` make sure that the reference to `wp-blog-header.php` is correct - it probably needs to be prefixed with a forward slash.

```
// wrong
require 'wordpwp-blog-header.php';

// correct, with forward slash
require 'wordp/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Comment: Does the index.php need to be in the /wordp directory now or in the root directory?

Comment: I'm not sure, I was just basing it on the error message - the path is missing a `/` between webp and index.php.